# Cannot Resolve Symbol 'analytics' When Using Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, android-studio, google-play-services

I am trying to implement Google Analytics in my app,

I have already created a global_tracker.xml file containing the basic configuration and my Property-ID.

I have added the meta-data tag to my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

These are the dependencies in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
}
```

I have created a class to store my tracker Enum as instructed in the [Google Analytics SDK V4 Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

But even after all of these steps, when attempting to import:

```
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Logger;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
```

I get an error saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'analytics' directing me to my import lines.

I have tried searching on the internet and in SO for a solution but didn't succeed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventully I found out what the issue was, my Android Studio project name **had an exclamation mark (!)** in it, causing the google play services to fail to attach itself to the project, making me unable to use the Google Analytics Library, aswell as other .jar files I wanted to add manually.

**Long story short, use the tips Android Studio displayes when you create a new project: avoid spaces and special characters when creating your project and developing it, as it might fail to work as expected**